# VotingAPI and Browser Fingerprinting

Tags: ajax, chaos-tool-suite, rating

I need better methods of ruling out cheaters in anonymous voting contests.  I'm using VotingAPI + vote_up_down, and those use ctools in some fashion for ajax.  I'm looking for any suggestions that could push me in the right direction.

I've not done must custom code, and from the looks of it the parameters are hardcoded into *everything*, so this appears to be a nontrivial modification (aka total hack).